# Multisig pallet mispricing bug?

Tags: existential-deposit, multisig

In the `pallet_multisig`, there are two storage maps `Multisigs` for the multisigs and `Calls` for the actual call in a multisig. The pallet has two distinct pricing components for its bloat deposit:

```
// One storage item; key size is 32; value is size 4+4+16+32 bytes = 56 bytes.
pub const DepositBase: Balance = deposit(1, 88);
// Additional storage item size of 32 bytes.
pub const DepositFactor: Balance = deposit(0, 32);
```

But when you look at how these are used, you see that `store_call_and_reserve` uses `data.encoded_len() + 31` as the byte length used with the `DepositFactor` to price the `Calls` mapping, despite the byte size of this needing to be `sizeof([u8; 32]||(OpaqueCall<T>, T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>)` which is something like `32 + data.encoded_len() + 32 + 128` in Polkadot/Kusama.

**Isn't this under pricing in this case?**

I ask because there is very scarce information on how storage deposits should properly be set, so I'm not totally sure I am interpreting everything properly.

**Side question:** Why would one split this representations into two distinct maps like this? It seems having call in multisig itself would be a safer static representation, now there is an implicit runtime invariant about maps being synchronised.